# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on setting up a basic RoR app. All my databases are MySQL and local, my database,yml file is included. I am trying to access a basic view but am still getting the ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error. What am I doing wrong?

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: *****_dev
  username: ****
  password: *****
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: *****_test
  username: ****
  password: *****
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: *****_prod
  username: ****
  password: *****
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

MySQL2 in the gem file:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.10'
```

So when go to type in: `http://localhost:3000/controller/view` I get: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

What else can I include that would be helpful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost does that work? Also what version of Rails? 3.2.6?

Comment: If I replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost, I get a socket error if I try to run rake db:migrate. With 127.0.0.1 rake db:migrate runs without error. Also, I am on rails 3.2.2. Thanks.

Comment: did you installed apache and mysql? what is the result after http://localhost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and check for the binding address of the mysql deamon. It probably doesnt bind to any ip. Then it will use unix sockets which are by the way faster then ip connections,...

Option name for the bind address is `bind-address` if theres no match it wont bind to any address. Also have a look for `socket` which specifies the path to the unix socket. You can use the socket like this in your `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: *****_dev
  username: ****
  password: *****
  socket: /path/to/the/socket/mysql.sock
```

That should do it for you,...